# Java Compilation Error: Could not find or load main file

Tags: java, compilation

I just compiled a class from the command line using `> javac -classpath src/foo src/foo/bar.java`, and it worked fine. However, when I try to run `> java -classpath bin/foo bin/foo/bar`, I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class bin/foo/bar`. Any idea what's causing this error?

Comment: Is the .class file actually in that location?

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the *class name*, not a filename. So you want:

```
java -classpath bin foo.bar
```

(Or something similar. It's not clear from your samples how you'd end up with the class files in the `bin` directory rather than `src`, given that you're not using `-d` as part of the `javac` command line...)

Comment: Ahh, that was my stupid mistake. I was using Eclipse before, which automatically put the `.class` files in a `.bin` folder. Now that I've moved the `.class` file, manually, into the `.bin` folder,, what should I do?

Comment: @Adam_G: You follow the instructions in the answer - specify the root of the class file hierarchy, and the fully-qualified classname. Note that the class file should be in a folder hierarchy matching the package hierarchy (e.g. if class `bar` is in package `x.y`, it should be in folder `x/y`.